# Flutter CRUD model with provider

Tags: flutter, mobile, crud, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I'm learning Flutter with Provider and trying to make a CRUD model. I've achieved the create part, read and the delete  part, but struggling with the update part of the model. I made and API call that reads and displays the data, made a method in which a new object is created and one for removing the object, but all is left is modifying/edit the object. Here is the code I've done so far:

The Vehicle list that calls the API:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/vehicle.dart';
import 'screens/vehicle_details_screen.dart';
import 'services/vehicle_api.dart';
import 'models/vehicle_data_provider.dart';

class VehicleList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VehicleList createState() => _VehicleList();
}

class _VehicleList extends State<VehicleList> {

  _getPosts() async {
    var provider = Provider.of<HomePageProvider>(context, listen: false);

    var postsResponse = await fetchVehicles();
    if (postsResponse.isSuccessful) {
      provider.setPostsList(postsResponse.data, notify: false);
    } else {
      provider.mergePostsList(postsResponse.data, notify: false);
    }

    provider.setIsHomePageProcessing(false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Consumer<HomePageProvider>(
          builder: (context, vehicleData, child) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: DataTable(
                      columnSpacing: 50,
                      columns: <DataColumn>[
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Friendly Name',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Licence Plate',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Delete',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: List.generate(
                        vehicleData.postsList.length,
                        (index) {
                          VehicleData post = vehicleData.getPostByIndex(index);
                          return DataRow(
                            cells: <DataCell>[
                              DataCell(
                                Text('${post.friendlyName}'),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              VehicleDetailsScreen(
                                                color: post.color,
                                                friendlyName: post.friendlyName,
                                                licencePlate: post.licencePlate,
                                              )));
                                },
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text('${post.licencePlate}'),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    vehicleData.deletePost(post);
                                  },
                                ),
                                // onTap: vehicleData.deletePost(post),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The vehicle details screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/vehicle.dart';
import 'models/vehicle_data_provider.dart';

class VehicleDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'vehicle_details_screen';
  final vehicleList;
  String color, friendlyName, licencePlate;
  VehicleDetailsScreen(
      {this.vehicleList, this.color, this.friendlyName, this.licencePlate});
  @override
  _VehicleDetailsScreenState createState() => _VehicleDetailsScreenState();
}

class _VehicleDetailsScreenState extends State<VehicleDetailsScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String color, friendlyName, licencePlate;
  final TextEditingController _controllerfriendlyName = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerlicencePlate = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerColor = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _controllerColor.text = widget.color;
      _controllerfriendlyName.text = widget.friendlyName;
      _controllerlicencePlate.text = widget.licencePlate;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerColor.dispose();
    _controllerfriendlyName.dispose();
    _controllerlicencePlate.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myProvider = Provider.of<HomePageProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Vehicle Details',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 400,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: new ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter friendly name';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        controller: _controllerColor,
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          color = value;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                          hintText: 'Enter friendly car name',
                          labelText: 'Name',
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          friendlyName = value;
                        },
                        controller: _controllerfriendlyName,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter vehicle model';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car_outlined),
                          hintText: 'Enter vehicle model',
                          labelText: 'Model',
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter some text';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        controller: _controllerlicencePlate,
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          licencePlate = value;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                          hintText: 'Enter manufactured year',
                          labelText: 'Year',
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Edit',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        _formKey.currentState.save();
////The method bellow updateList ()needs to be changed in order to modify the existing list, this method just creates a new one.
                        await myProvider.updateList(VehicleData(  
                          friendlyName: friendlyName.toString(),
                          color: color.toString(),
                          licencePlate: licencePlate.toString(),
                        ));
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the HomePageProvider model:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'models/vehicle.dart';

class HomePageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isHomePageProcessing = true;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  String friendlyName;
  List<VehicleData> _postsList = [];
  bool _shouldRefresh = true;

  bool get shouldRefresh => _shouldRefresh;

  setShouldRefresh(bool value) => _shouldRefresh = value;

  int get currentPage => _currentPage;

  setCurrentPage(int page) {
    _currentPage = page;
  }

  bool get isHomePageProcessing => _isHomePageProcessing;

  setIsHomePageProcessing(bool value) {
    _isHomePageProcessing = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<VehicleData> get postsList => _postsList;

  setPostsList(List<VehicleData> list, {bool notify = true}) {
    _postsList = list;
    if (notify) notifyListeners();
  }
// This method needs to be changed
  updateList(VehicleData list) {
    _postsList.add(list);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  mergePostsList(List<VehicleData> list, {bool notify = true}) {
    _postsList.addAll(list);
    if (notify) notifyListeners();
  }

  deletePost(VehicleData list) {
    _postsList.remove(list);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  addPost(VehicleData post, {bool notify = true}) {
    _postsList.add(post);
    if (notify) notifyListeners();
  }

  VehicleData getPostByIndex(int index) => _postsList[index];

  int get postsListLength => _postsList.length;
}
```

And this would be the Vehicle Data model:

```
class VehicleData {
  final String id,
      licencePlate,
      countryRegistered,
      type,
      color,
      vin,
      owner,
      garage,
      friendlyName,
      model,
      make,
      year,
      status,
      insuredBy,
      insurancePolicyNumber,
      policyExpirationDate,
      mobile,
      cellPhoneProvider,
      notes;
  final int capacity, co2perKm, luggageCapacity;

  VehicleData(
      {this.id,
      this.licencePlate,
      this.countryRegistered,
      this.type,
      this.color,
      this.vin,
      this.co2perKm,
      this.owner,
      this.garage,
      this.friendlyName,
      this.model,
      this.make,
      this.year,
      this.capacity,
      this.luggageCapacity,
      this.status,
      this.insuredBy,
      this.insurancePolicyNumber,
      this.policyExpirationDate,
      this.mobile,
      this.cellPhoneProvider,
      this.notes});

  factory VehicleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return VehicleData(
      id: json['id'],
      licencePlate: json['licencePlate'],
      countryRegistered: json['countryRegistered'],
      type: json['type'],
      color: json['color'],
      vin: json['vin'],
      co2perKm: json['co2perKm'],
      owner: json['owner'],
      garage: json['garage'],
      friendlyName: json['friendlyName'],
      model: json['model'],
      make: json['make'],
      year: json['year'],
      capacity: json['capacity'],
      luggageCapacity: json['luggageCapacity'],
      status: json['status'],
      insuredBy: json['insuredBy'],
      insurancePolicyNumber: json['insurancePolicyNumber '],
      policyExpirationDate: json['policyExpirationDate '],
      mobile: json['mobile'],
      cellPhoneProvider: json['cellPhoneProvider '],
      notes: json['notes '],
    );
  }
}
```

And the API call:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';;
import 'models/vehicle.dart';

Future<HTTPResponse<List<VehicleData>>> fetchVehicles() async {
  final response =
      await get('https://run.mocky.io/v3/d7a00528-176c-402f-850e-76567de3c68d');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
    List<VehicleData> posts = [];
    body.forEach((e) {
      VehicleData post = VehicleData.fromJson(e);
      posts.add(post);
    });
    return HTTPResponse<List<VehicleData>>(
      true,
      posts,
      message: 'Request Successful',
      statusCode: response.statusCode,
    );
  } else {
    return HTTPResponse<List<VehicleData>>(
      false,
      null,
      message:
          'Invalid data received from the server! Please try again in a moment.',
      statusCode: response.statusCode,
    );
  }
}
class HTTPResponse<T> {
  bool isSuccessful;
  T data;
  int statusCode;
  String message;
  HTTPResponse(this.isSuccessful, this.data, {this.message, this.statusCode});
}
```

Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'components/vehicle_list.dart';
import 'screens/settings_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/vehicle_data_provider.dart';

void main()  {
 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<HomePageProvider>(
            create: (_) => HomePageProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLocale>(create: (_) => AppLocale()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<AppLocale>(builder: (context, locale, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: VehicleList(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Like I said, I just need to update(edit) the existing data, which've passed from the one screen to another. Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong when it comes to updating the data. I understand the `updateList()` method is exactly the same as the addNew oneis not working but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Could you share the code where you have registered the `HomePageProvider`? It will help me understand the problem.

Comment: @PreetShah Added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So, I think I got it. The problem might be because you have two separate data sources. One is the API and the other is the `HomePageProvider` class. Now, what you're doing is that you're collecting data from the API and putting it in the `HomePageProvider` class. But every time the `VehicleList()` widget is called, the data is refreshed from the API. So, if you make any changes to your data in the `HomePageProvider` class, it will be overwritten by the data that comes from the API.

I would suggest you collect all the data in the `HomePageProvider` class itself and then call the API if and only if your `_postsList` variable has no data. Or determine some other measure to know if you should call the API or not. I would suggest using a `Set` instead of a `List`, if your data contains only unique values. It will help you avoid some unnecessary code.

Comment: I will try to change that. Is there any resource or a complete example of the of the idea you have mentioned? The thing that bothers is me is that I have done the other 3 but when it comes to update/edit, I don't quite understand what is wrong..

Comment: Let me know if my idea works. See, the thing is that you will need an architecture that separates Views, Models, Repositories and Controllers. Is there any function that will allow you to add data directly to the APIs database?

Comment: I though I have done this only with one model, when I call the API, the data is written in the provider(`HomePageProvider`), I have made an add and delete method, but I have not made a modify/edit method. Is there a way I can just make a method in the provider, or do I really need a method to send modified data back to the API and how if needed?

Comment: See, the thing is that you're retrieving the data directly from the API and putting it in the Provider. What you need to do is retrieve the data in the Provider. Because every time you load the Widget `VehicleList`, the function `fetchVehicles()` is called. So, new data will be overwritten in your Provider everytime. So, ensure that you call is once in your `HomePageProvider`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't understand how I am able to add new vehicles, delete them, but not modify them? Am I not setting the state of the widget in `initState` so it doesn't get called again, so I can change the data through Provider? Sorry to bother you so much with this, but I just can't do it, I've done all the rest but not modify/edit.

Comment: Do I need to send the modified data back to the API, or can I just make a method that handles the changes to the Provider. Also struggling with that, not sure what to do.

Comment: Well, there's too much to do here. The first thing you can do is create an API to modify the data. I don't know if it is your own API or not. If it is not your API, then modification of data can only be done locally. If it is your own API, make the necessary changes the best way you seem to understand it.

Comment: Is there a way I can edit the data only using provider in my example? Like I've done with the rest, I just called the API and stored the data in the provider, is it possible just to edit the data in the provider without calling the API again? Do I need just a method for that?

Comment: Try using the example provided over [here](https://maneesha-erandi.medium.com/handling-api-requests-with-flutter-provider-944e3258c5ca). Maybe, it will help you.